# Is there a way to route all commands through a shell script instead of running directly?

Tags: shell, executable

I want to be able to have everything being executed, rather than running the program, runs a shell script with the executable as the argument. It'd be nice to be able to do this without having to individually select all of the executables on the system.

Comment: I dont think that's possible without modify the shell. If you explained why you want to do this, maybe we can suggest an easier solution.

Comment: The idea is a signing idea, using a file full of signatures. I have a shell script that checks the executable against the file, and I want to put all input through that.

Comment: Depending on how thorough you need this to be, you may be able to just set PATH to a nonexistent or empty directory and hook into the shell's [command not found](http://superuser.com/questions/787424/hook-into-command-not-found-handler-in-ubuntu) functionality.

Comment: You can't do this: executing a shell would execute that script which would execute that script… You'll at least need to make an exception for that script and for the shell. [There's probably a better way to do whatever it is that you want to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to archieve that the command is completely send to a script, but in bash or in zsh you can add a hook usign the DEBUG trap which is called before each command.

For the details, please see https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command

Edit:
To stop a command, you can make it fail by changing the PATH variable. For example:

```
preexec() {
  if [ "$1" = "ls" ] ; then echo STOP; SAVEDPATH="$PATH"; export PATH=/DoesNotExist; 
  fi 
}

preexec_invoke_exec () {
  if [ "$SAVEDPATH" != "" ] ; then export PATH="$SAVEDPATH" ; unset SAVEDPATH ; fi;
  [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
  [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
  local this_command=`HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//"`;
  preexec "$this_command"
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

You will see that a command like `date` work normally, but `ls` fail with 'command not found'. But this way dows not work for shell builtin like `echo`.

Comment: Is there a way I can cancel the command from being run?

Comment: @MiseroMCS yes you can stop it by changing the PATH variable, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your path, then replicate a tree of all your executables to it, where each one is just another name for your script.  Something like :

```
$ mkdir ${HOME}/shell
$ OLDPATH=$PATH
$ PATH=${HOME}/shell:$PATH
$ echo $PATH | tr : \\n \
  | while read P; do (mkdir -p $(echo $P | sed s':/::'); ls $P/* ) \
  | while read F; do ln master_script $(echo $F | sed s':/::'); done \
    done
```

Now, write `master_script`.  Have it remove ${HOME}/shell from the PATH, use `command -v` to locate its name in the real path, and `exec` it with $@  as arguments.